# React Router doesn't match path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[image]

This is my routing configuration, when i access the index route which is "/"
it works perfectly fine, but when i access the /posts and /response route, it cant resolve it.

[image: Index route]

See that is my index route. and this happens when i go to posts or response route [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, first of all, it seems like you're using an unnecessary **Router** component, you can check here why: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router

Also, you can wrap your routes inside a **Switch** component, but you will have to change the order of them since a Switch only renders the first route that matches the path given. You can read more about that here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch. So your routes definition will become something like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/r1" render={() => <h1>route 1</h1>} />
    <Route path="/r2" render={() => <h1>route 2</h1>} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={SomeComponent} />
 </Switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping your all 3 `Route` inside a `Switch` statement